# How to remove old AutoPlay items in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, autoplay

How to edit the AutoPlay menu items in order to remove old items?

Adobe Lightroom creates with each version a new item but does not remove the old items.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Even though they are closely related, what you're dealing with is "[AutoPlay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun#AutoPlay)", not "[AutoRun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun#AutoRun)" ([distinction according to MS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Whats-the-difference-between-AutoPlay-and-autorun)).  Knowing that difference can make it much easier to find info when figuring out how to clean them out. :)

The AutoPlay handlers can be found in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\EventHandlers`.

To remove a handler, you should delete the associated registry key from both places.  As always, make a backup first.

[More info](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-remove-autoplay-handler-from-the-options-list-in-windows-xp-and-vista/).

Answer (score -1):

please go to:http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/CleanHandlers.shtml#download
and click the download button
enjoy!
Good bye.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, for example how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.